# How to change the behavior of sfWidgetFormSelectRadio in symfony?

Tags: symfony1, formatter

```
new sfWidgetFormSelectRadio(
                array('choices' => $images)));
```

The above will render each option something like:

```
<input type="radio" name="name" value="image_path">
```

How to make it render this way with minimal code:

```
<input type="radio" name="name" value="image_path"><img src="image_path" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested and straight from me reading the Symfony API docs [for that widget](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/widget/sfWidgetFormSelectRadio.class.php).  You'll need to extend the `sfWidgetFormSelectRadio` class, call it something like `myWidgetFormSelectRadio` and stick it in `lib/widget/myWidgetFormSelectRadio.class.php` in your project.

Override the `formatChoices()` method like so:

```
class myWidgetFormSelectRadio extends sfWidgetFormSelectRadio
{
  protected function formatChoices($name, $value, $choices, $attributes)
  {
    $inputs = array();
    foreach ($choices as $key => $option)
    {
      $baseAttributes = array(
        'name'  => substr($name, 0, -2),
        'type'  => 'radio',
        'value' => self::escapeOnce($key),
        'id'    => $id = $this->generateId($name, self::escapeOnce($key)),
      );

      if (strval($key) == strval($value === false ? 0 : $value))
      {
        $baseAttributes['checked'] = 'checked';
      }

      $inputs[$id] = array(
        'input' =>
          $this->renderTag('input', array_merge($baseAttributes, $attributes))
          . $this->renderTag('img', array('src' => self::escapeOnce($key))),
        'label' => $this->renderContentTag('label', self::escapeOnce($option), array('for' => $id)),
      );
    }

    return call_user_func($this->getOption('formatter'), $this, $inputs);
  }
}
```

so you're basically appending the `img` tag to the input.

In your form's `configure()` method you'll then need to switch from using `sfWidgetFormSelectRadio` to using `myWidgetFormSelectRadio` to use the new widget.

Let me know if this works ;-)

Comment: Glad to hear it! If it's the one that definitely worked for you, you might want to up your answer rate a bit (from 53%) and accept this answer... ;-)